# Accordion different widths jquery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I want to set accordion in this setup using jquery:

```
 |      Header 1      |
 |Header 2 | Header 3 |
 |      Header 4      |
```

Each one is an accordion item. Is it possible and how? I want also if header 2 is open to get header 3 opened.

TA

Comment: what about if header 3 is clicked... do you want header 2 to open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CppLB/1/

HTML:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="accordionButton">Header1</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">Content 1 goes here</div>
        <div class="accordionButton" class="buttonHalf">
            <div class="buttonHalf" id="borderRight">Header 2</div>
            <div class="buttonHalf">Header 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordionContent" class="buttonHalf">
            <div class="buttonHalf">Content 2 goes here</div>
            <div class="buttonHalf">Content 3 goes here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordionButton">Header 4</div>
        <div class="accordionContent">Content 4 goes here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

.accordionButton {    
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #003366;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    }

.accordionContent {    
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #95B1CE;
    display: none;
}

.buttonHalf {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}

#borderRight {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION    
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');    
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this sort of format:

```
|       Header 1       |
|   Header 2 Header 3  |
|       Header 4       |
```

where the header 2 header 3 part is just two bits of text in one header tag (or you can use tables in the header tag) and the div for that part of the accordion contains a table or css formatting to make the effect you described happen... if you want each headiing to look individual (with rounded corners) use css3.